# Could not load the file sensor_msgs/JointState.h

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, robot-state-publisher, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have an error with the package `robot_state_publisher` when I'm try to `catkin_make_isolated` with `ROS Melodic` on `Raspbian 9 (stretch)`.

Specifically, I get an error from the file `robot_state_publisher/include/robot_state_publisher/joint_state_listener.h` on line `43`.

`fatal error: sensor_msgs/JointState.h: No such file or directory`

However, the dependency `sensor_msgs` is correctly loaded in the `package.xml` file and the searched file exists at the indicated path.

Could you help me ?

Best regards,

Robin Hède.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323534/could-not-load-the-file-sensor_msgs/jointstate.h/) by [Robin Hède](https://answers.ros.org/users/41657/robin-h%C3%A8de/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-05-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-20**:
This would seem to be a cross-post of [ros/robot_state_publisher#110](https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/issues/110).

Cross-posting is considered bad practice. Please try to refrain from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution is available [here](https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/issues/110).

---

Originally posted by [Robin Hède](https://answers.ros.org/users/41657/robin-h%C3%A8de/) with karma: 16 on 2019-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-24**:
So do I understand your comment on [ros/robot_state_publisher#110](https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/issues/110) correctly when I believe you had a Catkin workspace seeded with a `.rosinstall` file that you generated using `rosinstall_generator` but you specified `ros_comm` as the base package instead of any of the variants defined in REP-150? Then adding `robot_state_publisher` (again: from source) to that workspace failed to build as it could not find `sensor_msgs/JointState`?

If yes: did you not get CMake errors telling you that it could not find the `sensor_msgs` package in your workspace?

**Comment by [Robin Hède](https://answers.ros.org/users/41657/robin-h%C3%A8de/) on 2019-05-24**:
Yes, I used ROS-Comm because this variant is listed in the [installation procedure](https://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source).

With this package path, I did not have the `robot_state_publisher` dependency require to install the `sick_tim` package.

Then, the mistake that I made was to clone the [git repository](https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher) directly into the source directory (~/ros_catkin_ws/src) instead of installing it cleanly.

From now on, I install everything directly via the command `rosinstall_generator robot sick_tim --rosdistro melodic --deps --tar > melodic-robot.rosinstall`.